# Attempted Alpha-Beta Pruning Implementation

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to write a program that plays Connect-K rationally, and I've written a long and iterative eval function. It doesn't play too poorly when run with the miniMax function, but when run with the alphaBeta function it returns the leftmost, bottom-most unoccupied move for some reason. I'm wondering if the problem I'm having is a part of my alphaBeta function or if it's somewhere else.

Pseudocode from Intro to Artificial Intelligence, 3rd edition that I attempted to implement.

```
function ALPHA-BETA-SEARCH(state) returns an action
  v ← MAX-VALUE(state,−∞,+∞)
  return the action in ACTIONS(state) with value v

function MAX-VALUE(state,α, β) returns a utility value
  if TERMINAL-TEST(state) then return UTILITY(state) 
  v ←−∞
  for each a in ACTIONS(state) do
    v ← MAX(v, MIN-VALUE(RESULT(s,a),α, β))
    if v ≥ β then return v
    α ← MAX(α, v)
  return v

function MIN-VALUE(state,α, β) returns a utility value
  if TERMINAL-TEST(state) then return UTILITY(state)
  v ← +∞
  for each a in ACTIONS(state) do 
    v ← MIN(v, MAX-VALUE(RESULT(s,a) ,α, β))
    if v ≤ α then return v
    β ← MIN(β, v)
  return v
```

Attempted implementation:

```
std::pair<int, Move> AIShell::alphaBeta(Tree t, int depth) {
    std::pair<int, Move> answer = maxValue(t, depth, -1000, 1000);
    return answer;
}

std::pair<int, Move> AIShell::maxValue(Tree t, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        Move m(t.howWeGotHere.first, t.howWeGotHere.second);
        std::pair<int,Move> answer;
        answer.first = Eval(t.potentialState);
        answer.second = m;
        return answer;
    }

    Move m;
    // Creates children
    for (int col=0; col<numCols; ++col) {
        for (int row=0; row<numRows; ++row) {
            if (t.potentialState[col][row] == NO_PIECE && inBattlefield(t.potentialState, col, row)) {
                std::vector<std::vector<int> > furtherState = t.potentialState;
                furtherState[col][row] = AI_PIECE;
                std::pair<int,int> pair(col,row);
                Tree child(furtherState, pair);
                t.children.push_back(child);
            }
        }
    }

    // Runs alpha-beta pruning
    std::pair<int,Move> answer;
    answer.first = -1000;
    for (size_t i=0; i<t.children.size(); ++i) {
        std::pair<int,Move> fromBelow = minValue(t.children[i], depth-1, alpha, beta);
        answer = answer.first > fromBelow.first ? answer : fromBelow;
        if (answer.first >= beta)
            return answer;
        alpha = std::max(alpha, answer.first);
    }
    return answer;
}

std::pair<int, Move> AIShell::minValue(Tree t, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        Move m(t.howWeGotHere.first, t.howWeGotHere.second);
        std::pair<int,Move> answer;
        answer.second = m;
        return answer;
    }

    Move m;
    for (int col=0; col<numCols; ++col) {
        for (int row=0; row<numRows; ++row) {
            if (t.potentialState[col][row] == NO_PIECE && inBattlefield(t.potentialState, col, row)) {
                std::vector<std::vector<int> > furtherState = t.potentialState;
                furtherState[col][row] = HUMAN_PIECE;
                std::pair<int,int> pair(col,row);
                Tree child(furtherState, pair);
                t.children.push_back(child);
            }
        }
    }

    std::pair<int,Move> answer;
    answer.first = 1000;
    for (size_t i=0; i<t.children.size(); ++i) {
        std::pair<int,Move> fromBelow = maxValue(t.children[i], depth-1, alpha, beta);
        answer = answer.first < fromBelow.first ? answer: fromBelow;
        if (answer.first <= alpha)
            return answer;
        beta = std::min(beta, answer.first);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Is there anything I'm not catching?

Comment: When you debugged your code, what did you discover?  Where does the program deviate from your plan or algorithm?

Comment: I'm writing in C++, so debugging is going to be a bit of a challenge, but I suppose that really is the next step. I just posted this wondering if there were any glaring flaws in that alpha beta function anyone could spot.

Comment: As long as there are no bugs in `Move` or `Tree` and that these types have correct copy semantics, you should be able to debug your code with very few surprises that are C++ language related.  In other words, your code is more or less straightforward (i.e. no tricky pointer usage, no memory allocation issues, etc.)

Comment: One thing to ask you -- you are passing `Tree t` by value.  Are you expecting your functions to change `t`?  If so, you aren't going to see the changes in `t` when the function returns.